# best way to lock an object

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I am building a program in C# with 2 Threads that use the same Object.
the first Thread updating the Object value and the second Thread printing it to the GUI.

I am searching for the most `correct` or `clean` way to implement the locking mechanism between the Threads.

an example of the implementation I have in my program (not the actual program):

```
namespace Test___Console
{
    public class Custom
    {
        public static object lockinObject = new object();
        public string name;
        public int value;
        public Custom(string name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
    public class Program
    {
        public static object lockinObject = new object();
        static Thread firstThread;
        static Thread secondThread;
        static public Custom someData;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            someData = new Custom("first");
            firstThread = new Thread(FirstThreadFunctions);
            secondThread = new Thread(SecondThreadFunctions);
            firstThread.Start();
            secondThread.Start();
            do
            {

        } while (true);
    }
    static void FirstThreadFunctions()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        do
        {
            someData.value = rnd.Next();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        } while (true);
    }
    static void SecondThreadFunctions()
    {
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine(someData.value.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        } while (true);
    }
}
}
```

I thought of 3 ways to lock the someData object

1.add get set with locking object to the someData object.

2.add get set with locking object to the Custom Class variables.

3.encapsulate all the code segments that use the same data object with locking statements(my least favorite method).

I don't have a lot of programming experience so I ask you what is the "correct" or "cleanest" way to deal with this problem.

Thank you

Comment: You can also lock your own classes `var c = new Custom(); lock (c) {...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to limit your blocking code as much as possible. Let's take your case for example.

Effectively, what you are trying to do is lock an object and prevent it from reading while it is written. No need to lock it while reading from other readers.

[ReaderWriterLockslim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim?view=netframework-4.8) to the resue. Then in your `Custom` class

```
public class Custom
{
    private ReaderWriterLockSlim cacheLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

    private int currvalue;
    public int value {
        get {
            cacheLock.EnterReadLock();
            var retValue = currvalue;
            cacheLock.ExitReadLock();
            return retValue;
        }
        set {
            cacheLock.EnterWriteLock();
            this.currvalue = value;
            cacheLock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    } 
}
```

This way, you are limiting concurrency only to the current object that needs to be thread safe, the lock is being applied very closely to the data so that no deadlocks will be easily introduced and only for the writting action.

Comment: Best approach would be to have one lock per group of correlating variables. That is, if var1 and var2 are totally independend but need to be handled, create a new lock for each one. If var2 needs to lock var 1 when writting, use a common lock for these. It all depends on the context. Limiting the locking areas is your target.

Comment: sorry, I deleted the comment (tried to post a comment from my smartphone but i could not jump a line).
the quastion was: what to do if my custom class have several variables?
thank you for your answer.
your meanning is that i need to add cacheLock.EnterReadLock(); (and the other corresponding commands) in each get and set of each correlating variable.
if the variables is independents i need to declare another ReaderWriterLockSlim secondCacheLock variable and use secondCacheLock .EnterReadLock(); (and the other corresponding commands).
i understood you correctly?

Comment: Yes! Exactly that. I know it's a bit of an overhead but it will save you time down the line.

Comment: This answer is wrong. You should always use `try... finally` to release locks or risk getting deadlocked if the thread gets cancelled or crashes between enter / exit. Also the question asks for best lock. For this case best lock would be to use the `Interlocked` class as this is a primitive type.

Comment: Charles, I added the documentation which indeed uses try finally. This is just an example. Interlocked is indeed for primitives, though the op just needed an example for properties.